# QFileDialog.getSaveFilename is not saving into any kind of file

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, python-3.5, pyqt5

I am trying to make a GUI which saves the content of a QTextEdit widget into a CSV file or a txt file. I just want it to save. I looked through a couple of questions and example and came up with these lines

```
def saveCSV(self):

    filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save File", 
         d.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%M")+".csv", "All Files (*);; CSV Files (*.csv)")
    if filename:
        with open(filename, "w") as file:
            file.write(self.textEdit.toPlainText())
            file.close()
```

But somehow when I click save, select the directory and save again, no file appears or is created. I've tried reading the doc but pyqt5 is only in C++ which I am not familiar with yet. Any insight?

Comment: Add some `print` statements to see what is happening.

Comment: Hi I found the answer, it seems I simply had to put `filename, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save File", 
     d.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%M")+".csv", "All Files (*);; CSV Files (*.csv)")` to make it work, altough I don't know why.

Comment: If you did as I suggested in my previous comment, it would be obvious why.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just found the answer on a youtube video, the line

```
filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save File", 
     d.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%M")+".csv", "All Files (*);; CSV Files (*.csv)")
```

Should be written as follow

```
filename, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save File", 
     d.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%M")+".csv", "All Files (*);; CSV Files (*.csv)")
```

Altough I found the answer I am not sure why I had to put an underscore. Could anybody enlighten me?